# Select Statement with Distinct returning multiple rows and need only first result

Tags: sql

I having a challenge with my query returning multiple results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gpph.id, gpph.cname, gc2a.assetfilename, gpph.alternateURL
FROM [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getpimproducthierarchy] gpph 
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2assetrefs] gc2a
ON gpph.id=gc2a.id
WHERE gpph.subtype='Level_4' AND gpph.parentId=@ID AND gc2a.assettype='Primary Image'
```

[image: result set]

A record, 5679599, has 2 'Primary Images' and is returning 2 results for that id but I only need the first result back.  Is there any way to do this IN the current query?  Do I need to write multiple queries?

I need some direction on how to constrain the results to only 1 result on Primary Image. I have looked at a ton of similar questions but most typically are just requiring the guidance of adding 'distinct' to the beginning of their query rather than on the where clause.

Edit: This problem is created by a user inputting 2 Primary Images on one record in the database. My business requirements only state to take the first result.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: How do you define 'first' - there is no ordering present in the query so when two records are found, what is the business rule for choosing 'first' - based on alphabetical order? a last updated date? random? (Any solution would need to know the rule)

Comment: It doesn't matter.  This problem is created by a user inputting 2 Primary Images on one record. My business requirements only state to take the first result. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the choice is arbitary which to return, we can just use an aggregate on the value. This then needs a `group by` clause, which eliminates the need for the distinct.

```
SELECT gpph.id, gpph.cname, max(gc2a.assetfilename), gpph.alternateURL
FROM [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getpimproducthierarchy] gpph 
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2assetrefs] gc2a
ON gpph.id=gc2a.id
WHERE gpph.subtype='Level_4' AND gpph.parentId=@ID AND gc2a.assettype='Primary Image'
GROUP BY gpph.id, gpph.cname, gpph.alternateURL
```

In this instance, using `max(gc2a.assetfilename)` is going to give you the alphabetically highest value in the event of there being more than one record. It's not the ideal choice, some kind of timestamp knowing the order of the records might be more helpful, since then the meaning of the word 'first' could make more sense.

Comment: Ok. I understand now.  In the future, I can suggest a timestamp and better return results. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace distinct to group by :

```
SELECT MAX(gpph.id), gpph.cname, gc2a.assetfilename, gpph.alternateURL
FROM [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getpimproducthierarchy] gpph 
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2assetrefs] gc2a
ON gpph.id=gc2a.id
WHERE gpph.subtype='Level_4' AND gpph.parentId=@ID AND gc2a.assettype='Primary Image'
AND gpph.id = MAX(gpph.id)
GROUP BY  gpph.cname, gc2a.assetfilename, gpph.alternateURL
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I get this error on the query above, "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: Edited to put the SQL in a code block, makes it easier to read - but I don't think this is right. The max in the where clause needs to be in a having clause to be legal syntax, but it still doesn't solve the problem.